# CMAKE, NMAKE makefiles - 'compiler cl not found' (but VS 12 generator succeeds)

Tags: visual-c++, makefile, cmake, visual-studio-2013

The VS environment variable is set beforehand with vcvars32.bat, and VS is the only compiler that I use; the OS is win 7.

The error happens with cmake-gui; specifying the compiler with path results in error 'compiler failed to make simple test'; alternatively, cmake -i from command line succeeds initially with presenting an 'options' menu which then fails to allocate a 'cmakelists.txt' file (which is somewhere deeper in the cmake folder).

Where am I going wrong?
(I continued with building the solution files from VS 12, but there's other issues.)

Comment: Are you run cmake and cmake-gui from "VS2012 Native Tools Command Prompt"? "Programs->Microsoft Visual Studio 2012->Visual Studio Tools"?

Comment: @Sergey I started cmake-gui as 'stand-alone', specified file path of source code and target folder for new build, and then for configuration NMAKE makefiles; tried VS 12 (for VS2013, I believe) to see if a compiler is recognised at all. Used VS2010 Command Prompt for setting environment path and trying cmake -i

Comment: Do not run cmake-gui as standalone. Run it from VS2012 Native Tools Command Prompt. This will help to generate nmake project. Will not work without "vcvars.bat" set.

Comment: @Sergey I see, think I'll either look at the CMakeFiles in more detail or probably try continue with the VS project files - many thanks for you help

Comment: @Sergey Realised the difference between just _starting_ cmake-gui from short-cut and from command prompt like you said, and re-tried - all good. You're a star

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question from [cmake mailing list](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2012-September/052012.html)

> Run cmake-gui FROM the target environment, just like you run cmake...
>
> i.e. : type "cmake-gui" in the cmd prompt that has your stuff set up
>   in it. Don't just launch it from a short-cut unless you're using the
>   "Visual Studio *" generators. Those do not need any special
>   environment. Many of the makefile ones do.