# CMake initial cache file's settings being ignored: its worked before

Tags: cmake

I'm worried that my Windows 8.1 OS may have been hacked because I can't think of any other reason for why this problem is happening.

Here's the contents of my cache file which has worked before:

```
set(WITH_SDL ON CACHE BOOL "")
set(WITH_AUDIO ON CACHE BOOL "")

set(WITH_MOVIES OFF CACHE BOOL "")
set(WITH_FREETYPE2 OFF CACHE BOOL "")
set(WITH_LUAJIT OFF CACHE BOOL "")
set(WITH_LIBAV OFF CACHE BOOL "")
set(BUILD_ANIMVIEWER OFF CACHE BOOL "")
set(BUILD_MAPEDITOR OFF CACHE BOOL "")

set(LUA_INCLUDE_DIR "C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.3.0/include" CACHE PATH "")
set(LUA_LIBRARY "C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.3.0/lua53.lib" CACHE FILEPATH "")
set(SDL_INCLUDE_DIR "C:/Users/Joseph/Programming/Github/Libraries/SDL2-2.0.3/include" CACHE PATH "")
set(SDL_LIBRARY "C:/Users/Joseph/Programming/Github/Libraries/SDL2-2.0.3/lib/x86/SDL2.lib" CACHE FILEPATH "")
set(SDL_INCLUDE_DIR "C:/Users/Joseph/Programming/Github/Libraries/SDL2_mixer- 2.0.0/include" CACHE PATH "")
set(SDL_MIXER_LIBRARY "C:/Users/Joseph/Programming/Github/Libraries/SDL2_mixer-2.0.0/lib/x86/SDL2_mixer.lib" CACHE FILEPATH "")
```

All the paths are still valid.

And here's the command I'm using:
`cmake -C "C:/Users/Joseph/Desktop/initial_cache.cmake" --build "C:/Users/Joseph/Programming/Github/CorsixTH/build" -g  "Visual Studio 12 2013" C:/Users/Joseph/Programming/Github/CorsixTH/`

The command terminal's output:

```
loading initial cache file c:/Users/Joseph/Desktop/initial_cache.cmake
-- Building for: Visual Studio 12 2013
Note: SDL audio is enabled (default)
Note: FFMPEG video is enabled (default)
Note: FreeType2 is enabled (default)
Note: Visual Leak Detector is disabled (default)

Building CorsixTH
-- Could NOT find SDL (missing:  SDL_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Error at CorsixTH/CMakeLists.txt:105 (message):
Error: SDL library not found, it is required to build.  Make sure the path
  is correctly defined or set the environment variable SDLDIR to the correct
  location

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Joseph/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

After the first successful use of this cache file I added more commands and then it stopped working so I removed the new commands but this didn't make it work again.

I've tried deleting the cmake cache by telling the CMake GUI to delete it and I've tried using a fresh download of the CorsixTH source code directory.

Comment: CMakeOutput.log: https://www.mediafire.com/?p23inkzs9mhojej

Answer (score 0):

If I look at [CrosixTH/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/CorsixTH/CorsixTH/blob/master/CorsixTH/CMakeLists.txt) and CMake's [Modules\FindSDL.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindSDL.cmake) the `SDLDIR` environment variable really has to be there (it is not cached and therefore read every time the configuration process starts again).

So I assume that what happened was the moment you changed something in your `CMakeLists.txt` you re-triggered `ZERO_CHECK` and your VS environment is missing the `SDLDIR` variable.

You you chould either:

- Add it to your global environment variables
- Add it to your VS project's environment variables (not yet possible with CMake itself)
- Add `set(ENV{SDLDIR} "C:/Users/Joseph/Programming/Github/Libraries/SDL2-2.0.3")` to your cache file (but that would be not comply with to put only cache variables in there)
- Write your own VS toolchain file for this kind of presets (that's what I've done to get those kind of things working reliable)

Some references:

- [CMake preload script for cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597673/cmake-preload-script-for-cache)
- [CMAKE, NMAKE makefiles - 'compiler cl not found' (but VS 12 generator succeeds)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887849/cmake-nmake-makefiles-compiler-cl-not-found-but-vs-12-generator-succeeds)
- [CMake feature request 0008884: Set Visual Studio project "custom environment variables" setting with CMake](https://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=8884)